# Tkinter function range issue

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, indexing

I am creating a TicTacToe game in tkinter, consisting of a 3x3 grid made out of buttons.

In the code below, once a player has drawn on a tile (by clicking on the button), the program should remove this tile from the list 'self.flattenedButtons'. This is to prevent the computer (player 2) from drawing on the same tile.

The method this check is made in is self.add_move(). This works on all buttons apart from the bottom right, I assume this is as I took away 1 from the ending range. If I do not do this I am given an 'out of range' error.

How would I change my method so it works on all buttons?

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from itertools import *
import random

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None): # init Window class
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # init Frame class
        self.master = master # allows us to refer to root as master
        self.rows = 3
        self.columns = 3
        self.guiGrid = [[None for x in range(self.rows)] for y in range(self.columns)] # use this for the computer's moves
        self.buttonText = StringVar(value = '')
        self.buttonText2 = StringVar(value = 'X')
        self.buttonText3 = StringVar(value = 'O')
        self.button_ij = None
        self.flattenedButtons = []
        self.create_window()
        self.add_buttons()

    def create_window(self):
        self.master.title('Tic Tac Toe')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        for i in range(0,3):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight = 1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)


    def add_buttons(self): 
        rows = 3
        columns = 3

        for i in range (rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                self.button_ij = Button(self, textvariable = self.buttonText, command = lambda i=i, j=j: self.add_move(i,j))
                self.guiGrid[i][j] = self.button_ij # place button into 2d array to access later on
                self.flattenedButtons.append(self.button_ij)
                self.button_ij.grid(row = i,column = j, sticky =E+W+S+N)

    def add_move(self, i,j):
          pressedButton = self.guiGrid[i][j]
          self.guiGrid[i][j].config(textvariable =self.buttonText2)

          for i in range(0, len(self.flattenedButtons)-1):
              if (self.flattenedButtons[i] == pressedButton):
                  self.flattenedButtons.remove(self.flattenedButtons[i])
                  print('removed')
              else:
                  pass


root = Tk() # creating Tk instance

rootWidth = '500'
rootHeight = '500'
root.geometry(rootWidth+'x'+rootHeight)

ticTacToe = Window(root) # creating Window object with root as master

root.mainloop() # keeps program running
```

Comment: I ran your code and I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I edited the code to include a print function. When I run the code and click on the bottom right button, 'removed' is not printed, showing the function does not work on this button. When I change the second parameter to len(self.flattenedButtons) I receive an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to operate the list when you iterate it.
If your code is:

```
          for i in range(0, len(self.flattenedButtons)-1):

              if (self.flattenedButtons[i] == pressedButton):
                  self.flattenedButtons.remove(self.flattenedButtons[i])
                  print('removed')
              else:
                  pass
          print(self.flattenedButtons)
```

You will see that your button 9 will never be removed.

Change your for loop to a easy list-comprehension:

```
self.flattenedButtons = [i for i in self.flattenedButtons if i != pressedButton]
print(self.flattenedButtons)
```

You will see the change.